# Is it legal to sell a product with a class 3 laser in Western Australia?

Tags: australia

Say the object isn't handheld and therefore doesn't meet the definition for laser pointer.

Comment: I had a look at the legislation on this a while ago, but I'm only coming back to it now - why do you suggest the distinction between a laser and a laser pointer is significant?